# Eclipse: How to Include Files in Build But Not in Export

Tags: java, eclipse, export, classpath

In Eclipse, I know how to include additional files in a build by adding them to the Build Path.  And I know how to exclude files from a build by adding include/exclude filters on the included folder.  But what I'm trying to figure out is how to do a combination of the two such as include a file in the build but not in the export.  And I want to do this without Ant, Maven, etc.

**Here's the situation:**

I have a simple Java project.  It includes a properties file with logon information for a server.  I want a build that will include this file in the classpath so that it is found while I'm developing and debugging in Eclipse.  But, when I'm ready to export a runnable .jar, I want it to exclude this file because it's a security risk, etc.

For sake of discussion let's assume this project structure:

```
MyProject
    +----bin
    +----lib
    +----src
    +----resources
             +----application.properties
             +----version.properties
```

Ideally, I'd like the build and the export to ignore application.properties but include version.properties.  Then at run time (both in Eclipse & from runnable .jar) I'd like the app to be able to find application.properties in the resources/ folder.

**Doesn't work:**

I've tried some variations like including the "resources" folder in the build path but excluding application.properties, But this seems to also prevent application.properties from being found at runtime.

**Solutions?**

I suspect that this fundamentally can't be done in Eclipse alone as it seems to require the file to be simultaneously both on and not on the buildpath.

I know that I can just open the .jar and remove the files.  This is probably what I'll end up with, but I'd rather have a cleaner solution for those who come after me.  This seems like it would be a common scenario -- configuration files kept out of a jar but kept on the build path.  How do you others handle this?

Comment: Add the things you need for running locally, but that should not be included in the JAR, to the launch configuration (tab _Dependencies_) instead of to the _Java Build Path_ of the project.

Comment: Thanks @howlger.  That's embarrassingly simple, don't know how I missed it.  If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add** the things you need **for running locally** and that should not be included in the JAR **to the launch configuration** (tab *Dependencies*) instead of to the *Java Build Path* of the project.